# Magento 2 import customer script

Tags: magento2, customer, import, script

Does anyone have a script for importing custom customer list form a csv or xml ?
i found the next script for magento 1: https://gist.github.com/peterjaap/5955852, but for magento 2 i can't find anything.

Can anyone give me the answer to this?
Or maybe a customer database diagram?

Comment: Any reason why not using the built-in Magento 2 customer import system ?

Comment: I have a MySQL database which is not in Magento.

Comment: What about exporting customers from your MySQL database then importing to magento 2 using the built-in import system ?

Comment: @AlinLupoiu Means you want to Import Customer Data using CSV file? Why don't you use Customer Import/Export Magento Feature

Comment: the are some extra fields in my csv files